# Windows 10 will not boot without recovery CD

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, dualboot

My primary desktop machine is running Windows 10 64-bit.  After another desktop had some hardware upgrades a few years ago (both were running Win 7 at the time and had the same Asus MV-M2A-MV HDMI mobo), I took its old 500GB IDE system HDD and put it in the primary machine and set it up for dual boot so I could access the old system (long story, I needed to access it for app settings and such).

The problem was that it required the Windows CD to be in the drive or it would give the "DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER" message.  I *just* have to have the CD inserted and then skip the "boot from CD" option, and Windows will start up.

I eventually upgraded the primary machine to Win 10 and formatted the IDE HDD to use as backup space, but the DISK BOOT FAILURE problem never went away.

Troubleshooting tried:

- I made sure the BIOS boot order is correct, even trying to set the Hard Disk as the 1st boot device with no luck.
- Ran Windows Startup Repair but it doesn't find any issues.
- Ran chkdsk and it says it finds no problems.
- Ran DISKPART but that's were I get a little unsure of what I might do to try to troubleshoot and/or fix the issue.  Here's what `list disk` shows me:

[image: DISKPART list disk]

I'm also unsure if the Disk Management has any relevant information.

[image: Windows Disk Management]

Is there anything in this information that might determine why I cannot boot without the DVD in place?